# c# - CookieException during CookieContainer.Add, part of the cookie is invalid

Tags: c#, cookies, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Windows Phone 8 application that needs to speak with a server. The server sets a cookie to my `HttpClient`'s client handler when I call the login service on the server (which is located under sub-directory "/authentication"). Then I take this `Cookie` and store it in the `IsolatedStorageSettings`. When I close and re-open my application, thus re-instantiating my `HttpClient`, I want to get the `Cookie` from `IsolatedStorageSettings` and set it to my client handler manually. However, I get a `CookieException` with the message: "The 'Domain'='mobile.some-domain.com' part of the cookie is invalid."

The code I wrote for this as follows:

```
public static void saveCookies()
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    var cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(ROOT + "/authentication"));
    settings["sessionCookie"] = cookies["JSESSIONID"];
    settings.Save();
}

public static bool checkCookies()
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains("sessionCookie"))
    {
        Cookie c = settings["sessionCookie"] as Cookie;
        Uri uri = new Uri(ROOT + "/authentication");
        handler.CookieContainer.Add(uri, c);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

ROOT is "https://mobile.some-domain.com/ERSMobileApps/services" and the type of handler is `HttpClientHandler`.

I'm dealing with cookies for the first time, so any help/comment on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckch3yd2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says: "If you add a Cookie instance for just one specific host, do not set the Domain property of the Cookie instance. This is set automatically, based on the URI." So, I changed changed `checkCookies` to be:

```
public static bool checkCookies()
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains("sessionCookie"))
    {
        Cookie c = settings["sessionCookie"] as Cookie;
        Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path);
        Uri uri = new Uri(ROOT + "/authentication");
        handler.CookieContainer.Add(uri, newCookie);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I doesn't have any problems so far.